# Ansible command module with nvm

Tags: linux, ansible, nvm

I am trying to execute this command using Ansible:

```
- name: install node v5.5.0
  sudo: yes
  shell: nvm ls-remote
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128
    https_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128
```

I tried shell and command.

When using command:  I got this error:

```
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2"
```

When using shell: I got this error:

```
"fatal: [gocdagent-dev-01.rno.apple.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "nvm ls-remote", "delta": "0:00:00.016365", "end": "2016-05-16 18:26:07.259729", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-05-16 18:26:07.243364", "stderr": "/bin/sh: nvm: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}"
```

I can execute `nvm` command directly on the system. Why can't Ansible run `nvm`?

Answer (score 3):

Nvm is not a binary, you have to load it first :

```
- name: install node v5.5.0
  shell: . <NVM_DIR>/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm ls-remote
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128
    https_proxy: http://17.99.193.229:3128
```

Comment: This results in `nvm.sh: Permission denied` event when using ```become: yes become_user: root ```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are running it as `root` (sudo: yes) in Ansible script. Make sure `nvm` is in root's PATH or give `/full/path/to/nvm` in shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I chased my tail for hours on this one. Olivier Lecrivain headed me in the right direction. This solved it.  This also gives you the ability to install multiple versions at the same time

```
- name: installing node versions using loop
  become: yes
  # Execute config files such as .profile (Ansible uses non-interactive login shells)
  become_flags: -i 
  become_user: yourdesireduser
  # $HOME will become yourdesireduser's home directory
  shell: ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install {{item}}"
  args:
    chdir: "$HOME/.nvm/"
    # not needed as it is created automatically through the nvm install command
    # creates: "$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v{{item}}"
  loop:
    - 14.18.3
```